# Sharding vs Partitioning database

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, mariadb, sharding

Sorry for the dumb question, I am not developer. I want solution for my database. I have zero user information in my database at the moment. I am thinking what if I have 1 million user information in future.

Please explain in simple words. I have a database in dedicated server.
And I want copy the database to 10 databases in 10 dedicated servers.

if user fills his information, like name, date or birth, address etc, The first 100 user information should go to first database and server. After 100k user information should go second database and server. And son on

I also want to search user information. ex. Sam Smith with date of birth in 10 database at same time

How that can be achieved?

Which one the solution. MySQL auto sharding,
MySQL partition.
Mongodb Sharding
Clustering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is for an important project with real-world consequences, hire a DBA to advise. If it's academic, explore how those work. There are many engineering blogs and presentations on how to scale these things. If anything, too many to list.

Answer (score 3):

1M rows in a table -- no problem.  Even 1 billion rows may not need any of those fancy actions.

Replication -- needed if you have 1000 *reads per second*.  Or you want a separate backup machine.

Partitioning -- won't help the use case you described.

Sharding -- only if you need to 1000 *writes per second*.

1M WordPress "users", each owning Database with something 26 tables and thousands of "posts"?  Then you have a problem.  (But mostly it is because of WP's choice of EAV schema design.)

Bottom line -- Re-ask your Question after you have 1 thousand "user information".  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With 1K, the dataset should be big enough to project what issue growth may present, but not so big that it will necessitate a long downtime.

Answer (score 0):

For mongoDB here is some info on both options since they provide different functionality:

1. sharding    -> horisontal read/write performance scalability ( if your single server cannot provide enougth performance and you cannot upgrade more when data grows in time then you need to shard )
2. replication -> high availability and redundancy ( if you want to reduce maintenance downtime and increase redundancy then you need to use replication to add more replicaSet members that will hold same data on different storages )